# Can the matrix multiplication be considered as a tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Give an example of a vector space $V$ and vectors $x,y \in V$ such that $x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x \in V \otimes V.$

Here is my solution:

Consider $V = M_2 (\mathbb R),$ the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb R.$ Then $ x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x$ where $\otimes$ is the matrix multiplication.

**My question is:**

Can the matrix multiplication be considered as a tensor product? Is my example correct?if not, could you please give me an example? as far as I know tensor product is commutative.

Comment: Well, tensor product of vector spaces is indeed commutative *up to isomorphism*, meaning $V\otimes W\cong W\otimes V$, however, for vectors.it is basically *pairing*. Just take $V=\Bbb R^2,\ x=(1,0)^T,\ y=(0,1)^T$. And no, matrix multiplication is not the tensor of two matrices as vectors, though that might also lead you to an example.

Comment: Did you really meant that $y$ to have a transpose?@Berci

Comment: Is not the example you gave is dot product and dot product is commutative? so it can not be an example?@Berci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to decide what $\otimes$ means in the space $V \otimes V$; it has a very precise meaning. In particular, you can't just say "$\otimes$ is matrix multiplication", because in fact $\otimes : M_2(\mathbb{R}) \times M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not matrix multiplication (it has the wrong codomain, for example!).

With that said, the formal definition of a symbol like $a \otimes b$ isn't actually that important. The really important thing is the universal property, which I'll give in specialized form here.

**Fact 1.** $\otimes : V \times V \to V \otimes V$ is bilinear.

**Fact 2.** If $T : V \times V \to W$ is bilinear, then there exists a unique linear map $\widetilde{T} : V \otimes V \to W$ such that $T(a,b) = \widetilde{T}(a \otimes b)$ for all $a,b \in V$.

Important examples of bilinear maps include many kinds of multiplication maps, like matrix multiplication $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \times M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$! Can you use Fact 2 to now prove that $x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x$ whenever $x, y \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ are matrices which don't commute?

For your answer to be fully complete, you should also give an actual example of two specific $2 \times 2$ matrices $x$ and $y$ such that $x \otimes y \neq y \otimes x$.